# Our Canon MX340 printer/scanner is connected wirelessly to my MacBook Pro, but I can't get the scanner function to show up anywhere

Tags: macbook-pro

I have tried adding a printer, hoping to see the scanner as a choice.  It isn't.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled, but still see nothing about a scanner option.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you elaborate on three things: what version of OS X are you running? Where specifically (screen shot would be ideal) are you hoping to see the scanner? What specific URL or directions or steps do you take for uninstall and reinstall? Please edit any/all of these into the body of the question to make the text flow naturally.

Comment: Have you tried running "image capture"?  If so does it list the MX340 as an available shared device?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
http://www.mac-forums.com/apple-notebooks/212319-canon-pixma-mx340-macbook-pro.html

Let us know if it does or not, please!